# Saving images in a HashMap Android

Tags: android

is it possible to save images from the MediaStore, based on a certain user action, in a key/value pair using Hashmap. what i mean is, if the app gets restarted, does the Hashmap retain the contents or would i have to perform the action again.

what other solutions can i use to save the images for fast retrieval?.. shared Preferences or sqlite database, but i am assuming the latter might just be a waste.

Hope i am clear on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HashMap would get destroyed when your application is destroyed & restarted.

One option would be to use your [applications cache directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) and define a mapping between your key and the filename in the cache folder.

Comment: thanks.. would look into how to use it. because i have never used it before. i once saw a solution like saving the Hashmap in a shared preference. would that also work?..

Comment: It may work, but it's not a great idea because there would be a lot of work in getting the data in a storable format. It's far easier to use a key -> filename conversion.